# Powershell to fetch all alerts from SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

How can I fetch all the alerts from all the Site Collections in SharePoint Online/Office 365 using PowerShell script?

Comment: I used Salaudeen Rajack's script, but modified it for modern authentication:
https://vladilen.com/office-365/powershell-script-to-fetch-all-alerts-from-sharepoint-online-site/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are no PowerShell Scripts available to retreive alerts from SharePoint Online (yet).

See: [Index of Windows PowerShell for SharePoint Online cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161364.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the sample script you can try to fetch all the alerts created in SharePoint online.

## Config Variables

$SiteURL = "https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/GA"

## Connect to PNP Online

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

## Fetch all the users from SharePoint online site

$users = Get-PnPUser

foreach($user in $users)
{
    $alerts = Get-PnPAlert -User $user
    #Check if user has any alerts created or not. 
    if($alerts -ne $null)
    {
     #Display the user details and alert title 
     Write-host -Object $user.Title, $user.email, $alerts.Title 
    }
}

Note: This can only be executed for site collection admin or owners permission. 
Pnp powershell you would need to install. 
Ref: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell

Comment: this approach worked for me, but only for small sites (a few site users). When number of site users is big - the loop will lasts forever...